# 'ElementNotVisibleException:element not interactable' error locating Google Search button even though element was waited for on Google Home Page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

So I have a Selenium test that waits for a button to load up before it interacts with it.

As seen in my code, I have implemented it so that the driver will wait 14 seconds (14 is just a random number), or it will move on if the element is located before 14 seconds.

However, even after I have waited for element to load, and I try to interact with it (using Click() method), I get this error showing that the element is not 'interactable'.

The funny thing is, this actually works some times- where the element is indeed interactable- but not other times.

```
public void TestChromeDriverMinimalWaitTime()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            //find search bar and enter text
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Selenium");
            //wait 14 seconds max..
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(14));
            //...unless button element is found
            IWebElement waitUntil = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Name("btnK")));
            //once found, click the button
            waitUntil.Click();
            //wait 4 secs till this test method ends
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
```

This is the error that I get:
Line 53 is the line that says: **waitUntil.Click();**

[image]

Revised working code based on @DebanjanB's answer:

```
public void TestChromeDriverMinimalWaitTime()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            //find search bar and enter text
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Selenium");
            //wait 14 seconds max..unless button element is found
            IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(14)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("btnK")));    
            //click enter
            element.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you code trials it seems you are trying to invoke `click()` on the button with text as **Google Search** on the [Google Home Page](https://www.google.com/).

Your approach inducing *WebDriverWait* was just perfecto. But if you analyze the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) you will find the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which you have adapted identifies **multiple (two)** elements within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). So the *locator* doesn't identifies the desired element uniquely. While execution the *locator* identifies the other element which is **not visible**. Hence you see the error as:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable
```

---

### Solution

The easiest approach here is, as the *search box* which you have identified as:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Selenium");
```

is within a *form*, once you send the *search text* you can use either of the following solutions:

- Sending `Keys.Return` as follows:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("q")));
  element.SendKeys("Selenium");
  element.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
  ```
- Sending `Keys.Enter` as follows:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("q")));
  element.SendKeys("Selenium");
  element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
  ```

Comment: Regarding your solution(s), the first line does not compile as the Click() method returns void, and it would not allow us to convert to IWebElement type

Comment: That was my bad, corrected it. Let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks for that, works perfectly (no more funny business, at least for now!). I had actually tried to use the 'ExpectedConditions' method before, but it wasn't being found. I just then found that I had to add a Nuget package 'DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers' for the method to work.

Comment: Regarding your solution(s), so you're saying that my previous code was not uniquely identifying the specific element all the time?

Comment: Can you undo the Nuget package change please, because it doesn't correspond to the original issue in my question. The Nuget package was only mentioned after you included the 'ExpectedConditions' in your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that- all sorted now

Answer (score 1):

With it working sometimes, it seems like a timing issue. Perhaps the element starts out disabled, and is enabled after some tiny delay, or an event. Try adding a delay just before .Click. You might also check the state of the button element to see if it is disabled.

Comment: Thanks @Thoryn, I did think of that but I was wondering whether its good to add a lot of sleep delays within tests. Is this good practice or is it a necessary thing that we just have to do, to wait for elements to load?

Comment: Checking state is usually better than a static delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the visibility of an element in the page using the below code.

```
public void TestChromeDriverMinimalWaitTime()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            //find search bar and enter text
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Selenium");

            //...unless button element is found
           while(!IsElementVisible(driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnK"))){
                  Thread.Sleep(1000);
                  }
            //once found, click the button
            waitUntil.Click();
            //wait 4 secs till this test method ends
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

public bool IsElementVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return element.Displayed && element.Enabled;
}
```