# Element not interactable error clicking on Google Search button on Google homepage using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("../drivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys('Google')
driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
print("Test completed")
```

This is the code and I am getting an error like:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on <kbd>Google Search</kbd> button, as the element is within a `<form>` you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `submit()`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://google.com")
  element = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
  element.send_keys('Google')
  element.submit()
  driver.quit()
  print("Test completed")
  ```
- Using `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://google.com")
  element = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
  element.send_keys('Google')
  element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  driver.quit()
  print("Test completed")
  ```
- Using `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://google.com")
  element = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
  element.send_keys('Google')
  element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  driver.quit()
  print("Test completed")
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on <kbd>Google Search</kbd> button, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `submit()`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://google.com")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  element.send_keys('Google')
  element.submit()
  driver.quit()
  print("Test completed")
  ```
- Using `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://google.com")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  element.send_keys('Google')
  element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  driver.quit()
  print("Test completed")
  ```
- Using `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://google.com")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  element.send_keys('Google')
  element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  driver.quit()
  print("Test completed")
  ```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- ['ElementNotVisibleException:element not interactable' error locating Google Search button even though element was waited for on Google Home Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55713414/elementnotvisibleexceptionelement-not-interactable-error-locating-google-sear/55715154#55715154)